# How will I set viewpager options in TabLayout in android for different users requiring login?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am currently working with an app where I have added some ViewPagerAdapters like this:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
                ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                adapter.addFragment(new FragmentA(), "A");
                adapter.addFragment(new FragmentB(), "B");
                adapter.addFragment(new FragmentC(), "C");
                adapter.addFragment(new FragmentD(), "D");
                adapter.addFragment(new FragmentE(), "E");
                adapter.addFragment(new FragmentF(), "F");

                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

I want to show the A, B and C fragments at the opening of the app. Then if any user logs in to the app, they will show A, B, D, E and F fragments.

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem with `if (loggedIn) { adapter.addFragment(new FragmentD(), "D"); } else { adapter.addFragment(new FragmentC(), "C");}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Put condition inside your getcount() something like below :

```
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
     if(isUserLoggedIn()){
      return 6;//fragment count for logged in users
     }
     else{
      return 3;//fragment count for non logged in users
     }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is this code right for check isUserLoggedIn()

    `public boolean isUserLoggedIn(){

        return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, false);

    }`